# What is it called when some pronounces their “t” sharply

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, speech

What is it called when people pronounce their "t" sounds so sharply that it sounds like the sound "eh" comes after the "t" sound?  So the "t" sound sounds like "teh" with a big emphasis on the "eh" sound?

Example: smart-eh

```
     first-eh
```

Answer (score -1):

It is called a *plosive*:

> [**plosive**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plosive) [noun]
>
> A consonant that is produced by stopping the airflow using the lips, teeth, or palate, followed by a sudden release of air. The basic plosives in English are t, k, and p (voiceless) and d, g, and b (voiced).

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: This describes the **usual** pronunciation.